# How to handle the virus on my router?

Tags: network, virus, nmap, router

I believe my router is infected with a virus. If it is, it has been infected for a large period of time (perhaps a year or more). Though, I only started to consider it being a virus around a week ago.

I forgot my password to the router in question and can't connect to it. I suppose there is a chance that if it's infected, the virus may have changed the password. I've heard that viruses on the routers are stored in RAM and that changing the administrator password after a restart might help, but I've also heard there are viruses that remain after a restart and start requesting their home for a payload.

I want to get rid of this virus completely, but before that I'd like to figure out where it came from (possibly by tracing it's signals) and what it does. What would be a way to go about doing this?

If it will request home for a payload (after restart) there is a chance that I could somehow monitor where it's trying to connect, but there is also a chance that the virus might be removed or start sleeping etc., then I won't be able to find it.

**So how is it possible to gather as much information about the virus (where it came from and what it does) as possible?
How can I remove it completely (without it coming back after a restart)?**

I have provided some information from an Intense Scan with NMap, which scanned all TCP Ports (I have only posted the information that can be useful).

I suppose **rtsp** explains why google always asks me to perform robot/human checks.

```
It is an ordinary home network.
Here is the information about the router:
Zyxel router.
Open ports:
23/tcp
80/tcp
53/tcp
43254/tcp - seems to be the one, the virus is using

Scanning 4 services on 192.168.1.1
WARNING: Service 192.168.1.1:43254 had already soft-matched rtsp, but now soft-matched sip; ignoring second value


43254/tcp open  rtsp
| fingerprint-strings: 
|   FourOhFourRequest, GetRequest: 
|     HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 134
|     Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp. UPnP/1.1 MiniUPnPd/1.8
|     Ext:
|     <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server.</BODY></HTML>
|   GenericLines: 
|     501 Not Implemented
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 149
|     Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp. UPnP/1.1 MiniUPnPd/1.8
|     Ext:
|     <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server.</BODY></HTML>
|   HTTPOptions: 
|     HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 149
|     Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp. UPnP/1.1 MiniUPnPd/1.8
|     Ext:
|     <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server.</BODY></HTML>
|   RTSPRequest: 
|     RTSP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 149
|     Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp. UPnP/1.1 MiniUPnPd/1.8
|     Ext:
|_    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server.</BODY></HTML>
|_rtsp-methods: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
1 service unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprint at https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?new-service :
SF-Port43254-TCP:V=7.50%I=7%D=8/28%Time=5B8500A3%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu%r(G
SF:enericLines,12F,"\x20501\x20Not\x20Implemented\r\nContent-Type:\x20text
SF:/html\r\nConnection:\x20close\r\nContent-Length:\x20149\r\nServer:\x20Z
SF:yXEL\x20Communications\x20Corp\.\x20UPnP/1\.1\x20MiniUPnPd/1\.8\r\nExt:
SF:\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501\x20Not\x20Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BOD
SF:Y><H1>Not\x20Implemented</H1>The\x20HTTP\x20Method\x20is\x20not\x20impl
SF:emented\x20by\x20this\x20server\.</BODY></HTML>\r\n")%r(GetRequest,122,
SF:"HTTP/1\.0\x20404\x20Not\x20Found\r\nContent-Type:\x20text/html\r\nConn
SF:ection:\x20close\r\nContent-Length:\x20134\r\nServer:\x20ZyXEL\x20Commu
SF:nications\x20Corp\.\x20UPnP/1\.1\x20MiniUPnPd/1\.8\r\nExt:\r\n\r\n<HTML
SF:><HEAD><TITLE>404\x20Not\x20Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not\x20Found<
SF:/H1>The\x20requested\x20URL\x20was\x20not\x20found\x20on\x20this\x20ser
SF:ver\.</BODY></HTML>\r\n")%r(HTTPOptions,137,"HTTP/1\.0\x20501\x20Not\x2
SF:0Implemented\r\nContent-Type:\x20text/html\r\nConnection:\x20close\r\nC
SF:ontent-Length:\x20149\r\nServer:\x20ZyXEL\x20Communications\x20Corp\.\x
SF:20UPnP/1\.1\x20MiniUPnPd/1\.8\r\nExt:\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501\x20
SF:Not\x20Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not\x20Implemented</H1>The\x
SF:20HTTP\x20Method\x20is\x20not\x20implemented\x20by\x20this\x20server\.<
SF:/BODY></HTML>\r\n")%r(RTSPRequest,137,"RTSP/1\.0\x20501\x20Not\x20Imple
SF:mented\r\nContent-Type:\x20text/html\r\nConnection:\x20close\r\nContent
SF:-Length:\x20149\r\nServer:\x20ZyXEL\x20Communications\x20Corp\.\x20UPnP
SF:/1\.1\x20MiniUPnPd/1\.8\r\nExt:\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501\x20Not\x2
SF:0Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not\x20Implemented</H1>The\x20HTTP
SF:\x20Method\x20is\x20not\x20implemented\x20by\x20this\x20server\.</BODY>
SF:</HTML>\r\n")%r(FourOhFourRequest,122,"HTTP/1\.0\x20404\x20Not\x20Found
SF:\r\nContent-Type:\x20text/html\r\nConnection:\x20close\r\nContent-Lengt
SF:h:\x20134\r\nServer:\x20ZyXEL\x20Communications\x20Corp\.\x20UPnP/1\.1\
SF:x20MiniUPnPd/1\.8\r\nExt:\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404\x20Not\x20Found
SF:</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not\x20Found</H1>The\x20requested\x20URL\x20wa
SF:s\x20not\x20found\x20on\x20this\x20server\.</BODY></HTML>\r\n");
MAC Address: [---i wont share it---] (ZyXEL Communications)
Device type: WAP
Running: ZyXEL embedded
OS details: ZyXEL Keenetic Giga WAP 2.04 - 2.05
Uptime guess: 1.111 days (since Mon Aug 27 08:20:50 2018)
Network Distance: 1 hop
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=201 (Good luck!)
IP ID Sequence Generation: All zeros
Service Info: Device: broadband router
```

FINGER PRINT IN HUMAN READABLE FORM:

```
SF-Port43254-TCP:V=7.50%I=7%D=8/28%Time=5B8500A3%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu%r(GenericLines,12F," 501 Not Implemented
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 149
Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp\. UPnP/1\.1 MiniUPnPd/1\.8
Ext:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server\.</BODY></HTML>
")%r(GetRequest,122,"HTTP/1\.0 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 134
Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp\. UPnP/1\.1 MiniUPnPd/1\.8
Ext:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server\.</BODY></HTML>
")%r(HTTPOptions,137,"HTTP/1\.0 501 Not Implemented
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 149
Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp\. UPnP/1\.1 MiniUPnPd/1\.8
Ext:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server\.</BODY></HTML>
")%r(RTSPRequest,137,"RTSP/1\.0 501 Not Implemented
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 149
Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp\. UPnP/1\.1 MiniUPnPd/1\.8
Ext:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>501 Not Implemented</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Implemented</H1>The HTTP Method is not implemented by this server\.</BODY></HTML>
")%r(FourOhFourRequest,122,"HTTP/1\.0 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 134
Server: ZyXEL Communications Corp\. UPnP/1\.1 MiniUPnPd/1\.8
Ext:

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server\.</BODY></HTML>
");
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a list of reasons why I think there is a virus in the first place:

- a strange open port with rtsp;
- some applications on my phone say that the network is not secure and has strange activity on it (yet only my phone was on the network at that time and it has no viruses that I am aware of);
- google asks for robot/human checks all the time. It gets automated signals, but they don't appear to be coming from the devices within the network;
- my social network account was hacked about a week or two ago. I have restored access to it.

P.S.
If you have any questions or tips on how I can better ask my questions, please feel free to suggest them in the comments.

P.P.S.
Found this interesting article: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/vault-7-wikileaks-divulges-cia-tool-for-capturing-rtsp-and-h-264-video-streams/
It might be related to my issue.

Comment: Why do you think there is a virus on your router? What symptoms are you seeing which it causes?

Comment: @Matthew As, I have mentioned in my post - a strange open port with rtsp + some applications on my phone say that the network isnt secure and has strange activity on it (yet only my phone was on the network at that time and it has no viruses) + google asks  for robot/human checks all the time. It gets automated signals, but they come not from the devices within the network.

Comment: @Matthew I have now added this info to the post

Comment: Some routers come with media streaming built in - seems an odd port to use, but not impossible - and Google asking for robot/human checks all the time seems pretty normal, and can be down to things like blocking cookies in the browser - I have clicked on more road signs than I can count. What applications are saying that the network is insecure?

Comment: @Matthew Banking application. It allows to connect to your bank account and manage it. When I tried to log in, it alerted, that the network isnt secure, and that it cannot allow for the connection to be established.

Comment: First , search your router model and check whether it is susceptible to easy hacking.

Comment: You might want to load up wireshark and MAC spoof the router, see what type of traffic is passing on that suspicious port

Comment: The suspicious port looks like upnpd. Is there anything else indicating malware?

Comment: @vidarlo well, I wrote the four reasons to consider it being a malware above.

Comment: If you are suspecting that your router is compromised and now intercepting communications between your devices and for example your social media or banking portals there should be easy ways to check for that just by verifying the TLS certificates and that you are talking to the right server. Your browser or even the applications will indicate whether that is the case.

Comment: @bfloriang the certificates are fine. Atleast at this moment. I usually try to be aware of them. Though, there is a chance, that I was not so aware, when my social network account was hacked.

Comment: So, considering the downvote and the meaning of a few comments and one answer (the one, which I did not accept), people here are more concerned about not caring about security, and saying that everything fine as it is. I imagine you guys on a job telling your bosses, that you have fixed all of the security issues, as there were none (because, there are just always nothing to worry about). Really, who de hell would care about security... The true security expert always has a reliable network and computers (just because he never considers them to be unreliable (HA!)). *Write this joke down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by trying to protect the router. According to Speednet.com, VPNFilter is a new type of malware designed specifically to target internet routers. It’s capable of collecting communication information from your router, attacking other computers, and destroying your device remotely. According to Cisco, the malware has already infected over 500,000 routers around the world.

Not all routers are susceptible to VPNFilter, but a few of the major brands are at risk.
The easiest (and currently, the only) way to fully remove VPNFilter is to do a factory reset. Typically, that involves pressing down the power button for 5-10 seconds, but you may want to double check based for your specific router model.

If you don’t want to do a full factory reset (which can clear important data from the device), you can also simply reboot your router. This won’t kill VPNFilter entirely, but it will drop the malware back to its initial stage and buy you some time.
Once you’ve wiped your router, there are few ways to keep yourself protected moving forward.

First, make sure you’re running the latest firmware by logging into your router account in an internet browser and checking for updates. You should also change the admin password for an extra layer of protection.

Finally, make sure that remote management is turned off. This will block hackers from controlling your router without your permission. That should keep you safe from any future malware attacks as well.
As far as seeing what is happening with virus, this would help.  When troubleshooting unknown open ports, it is useful to find exactly what services/processes are listening to them. This can be accomplished in both Windows command prompt and Linux variants using the "netstat -aon" command.

As far as RTSP goes, according to Juniper.net,  Rapid Tree Spanning Protocol (RTSP) is the default spanning-tree protocol for preventing loops on Ethernet networks. Spanning Tree Protocols Help Prevent Broadcast Storms.

I would also make sure to change admin password and MAC if possible.

Comment: The question mentions `RTSP`, rather than `RSTP` - the rest seems sensible enough though.

Answer (score 1):

> a strange open port with rtsp;

RTSP is the real time streaming protocol. But the header clearly says UPnP, so my guess is that `nmap` misidentified the service running. Most consumer routers support UPnP.

> some applications on my phone say that the network is not secure and has strange activity on it (yet only my phone was on the network at that time and it has no viruses that I am aware of);

What *exactly* does the app say? Is the network secured with for instance WPA2, or only WEP or even no security? Have you installed any third party certificates on your phone? Which app tells you this?

I would not place a lot of faith in what a smart phone app tells you.

> google asks for robot/human checks all the time. It gets automated signals, but they don't appear to be coming from the devices within the network;

Which external IP does the router have? If you have an ISP that does Carrier Grade NAT or proxying of HTTP requests, or use a VPN, google may challenge you with those checks. This indicates many requests, which may or may not be due to malware. It's **not** a *strong* indicator of malware in my opinion.

> my social network account was hacked about a week or two ago. I have restored access to it.

Facebook uses https and have preloaded HSTS in all major browsers. Malware on the router level will not be able to intercept such traffic, without placing a third party certificate in your OS' root certificate store.

In short; Your router **may** have malware, but the reasons you give is not really convincing to me, and I would look into and try to understand each of the points before jumping to conclusions, as you do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. If you would read the comments above, you would see, that I have described the application, which was triggering the alert and what it said. It was a banking  application. The level of security it excpects is out of doubt. 2. The network is secured with WPA2.

Comment: 3. It is better to listen to people, who say be vigilant in every situation and excepct the worst, then to those who say, that everything is fine, and no actions are required. The first ones solve the problems, while the rest get into trouble. That being said, your answer does not help to resolve the problem. (When it comes to security, it is even better to consider a device to be infected, even if no reasons exist. Just checking or reseting it time to time.)

Comment: @Mee Stating it's a banking app essentially gives us **zero** new information. Any sane banking app would not care about network security anyway, but use TLS to ensure that a secure channel can be established over a insecure network.

Comment: @mee and for your second point; being vigilant is a good thing. But focusing on the wrong things may make your overall security worse. My answer does not answer your question, because I believe your question is fundamentally flawed. None of the things you list is indicating any malware, and I give reasons why.